# How to print variable for, in outside for, in golang?

Tags: go

I have problem how to print a variable for, in outside for, in Go?
I'm using library GJSON [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson)

I have try many way , I just entered the global variable but just appear final index,
like:

```
datePriodGlobal = DatePeriod.String()
```

and

datePriodGlobal = DatePeriod.String()

another way I try but appear just final index too, like below:

```
tempPayments:= "Envelope.Body.GetCustomReportResponse.GetCustomReportResult.ContractSummary.PaymentCalendarList.PaymentCalendar."
resultMapPriodTest := gjson.Get(jsonString,tempPayments + "#.Date")
    resultContractsSubmittedTest := gjson.Get(jsonString, tempPayments + "#.ContractsSubmitted")

    var datePriodGlobal string
    for _, DatePeriod := range  resultMapPriodTest.Array()[1:13] {
        datePriodGlobal = fmt.Sprintf("%s", DatePeriod.String())
    }

    var contractsSubmittedGlobal string
    for _, ContractsSubmitted := range resultContractsSubmittedTest.Array()[1:13]{
        contractsSubmittedGlobal = fmt.Sprintf("%s", ContractsSubmitted.String())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s |        %s              \t|",datePriodGlobal, contractsSubmittedGlobal)

    }
```

I have json like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show `DatePeriod` struct and message error?

Comment: @KibGzr I have add tempPayments containts root to node , I'm using library gjson

Comment: "but appear just final index". I'm not sure what else you expect. You are assigning to datePriodGlobal over and over again (overwriting it in every iteration), and then afterwards print it once. Of course that's going to print the last value only. You should add your expected output to the question. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Just a bit later, Peter said what I was typing - the line `contractsSubmittedGlobal = fmt.Sprintf("%s", ContractsSubmitted.String())` doesn't append the string, it just overwrites it each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cannot use 'DatePeriod' (type Result) as type string in assignment"

So, the variable `DatePeriod` is a `Result` type, not a `String`. You're specifying you want to print a string with `%s`, but not giving `fmt.Sprintf` a string, causing that error. The `Sprintf` is unnecessary if the value given was already a `String`.

Looking at [gjson.go](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson/blob/master/gjson.go), the `Result` type has a `String()` method, so you'd want instead `DatePeriod.String()`.

EDIT:

From your latest edit, I think I see your second issue. Your loops replace the `...Global` string variables each time, so you'll only ever get the last value in the slice you've passed to `range`. Since your slices are identical in length, you might be better off with something like this:

```
resultMapPriodTest := gjson.Get(jsonString,tempPayments + "#.Date")
resultContractsSubmittedTest := gjson.Get(jsonString, tempPayments + "#.ContractsSubmitted")

dateArray := resultMapPriodTest.Array()[1:13]
contractsArray := resultContractsSubmittedTest.Array()[1:13]
for i := 0; i<len(dateArray); i++ {
    d := dateArray[i].String()
    c := contractsArray[i].String()
    fmt.Printf("%s |        %s              \t|", d, c)
}
```

Comment: still not appear, I try that way too, I 'm update my question I have try with .String()

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover your second issue, as well. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest just iterate over the `PaymentCalendar` as a slice of JSON objects rather than querying each field using the indexes as their pseudo-ids.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
func main() {

    jsonString := `
{
    "PaymentCalendarList": {
        "PaymentCalendar": [
            {"ContractSubmitted": 10,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T01:01:01"},
            {"ContractSubmitted": 20,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T02:02:02"},
            {"ContractSubmitted": 30,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T03:03:03"}
            {"ContractSubmitted": 40,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T04:04:04"}
            {"ContractSubmitted": 50,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T05:05:05"}
        ]
    }
}`

    result := gjson.Get(jsonString, "PaymentCalendarList.PaymentCalendar")

    for _, paymentCal := range result.Array()[0:3] {

        date := paymentCal.Get("Date")
        contractSubmit := paymentCal.Get("ContractSubmitted")

        fmt.Printf("%s | %s\n", date, contractSubmit)
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RIfDwK93tNF)

Comment: how to loop #.Date , your code problem with #.Date ?

Comment: No, this is actually working. I do not need to use `#` since `PaymentCalendar` is already an array.